# C# - Cutting HTML String into separate lines without breaking HTML tags

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to break a HTML content string in to multiple lines...

And each line should have some fixed characters, 50 or 60

Also I don't want to break the word..or html tags...

ex : <p>Email: <a href="mailto:someone@gmail.com">someone@gmail.com</a></p>
<p><em>"Text goes  <font color=red>Hello  world</font>  Text goes  here  and Text goes  here &nbsp Text goes  here  1976."</em> </p>

How can I acheive this in C# ?

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need a HTML parser, and then you will have to serialize it again.
Instead of creating your own parser and serializer you should look into existing libraries.

For the parser I recommend the OSS [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Kirk I just finished editing my answer when I saw your comment

Comment: Do I really need to use HTMLAGILITYPack bcoz my content shows in only one place and the max character would be 500.

Comment: @Either do you do it manually without programming, or you will have to parse the HTML. If the HTML is XML compliant (ie. XHTML) maybe you can also use a XML parser. If don't want to use either you'll have to write your own.